# Match multiple regex groups on different lines from a tex to print into csv

Tags: regex, csv, sed, latex, multiline

I have a beamer latex file, in that file some frames have the form

```
\frame{\frametitle{Title01}
Sub01\\
\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black}\\
\rowcolor{white}\\
\rowcolor{green}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

I would like to end up with a csv format like

```
Title01,Sub01,black,white,green
Title02,Sub02,red,white,blue
```

So far I have managed to get all the titles with

```
sed -rn 's/^.*frametitle\{(.*)\}/\1,/pm' f.tex
```

I am failing to match the second group Sub01 (for now with latexlinebreak \) in the next line, a small selection of what I have tried so far

```
sed -rn 's/^.*frametitle\{(.*)\}\n(.*)$/\1,\2/mp' f.tex
sed -rn 's/^.*frametitle\{(.*)\}$^(.*)$/\1,\2/mp' f.tex
sed -rn 's/^.*frametitle\{(.*)(\}\n)(.*)$/\1,\3/mp' f.tex
sed -rn 's/^.*frametitle\{(.*)\}\n(.*)\n/\1,\2/mp' f.tex
```

all matching either just the title or nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\\frame{\\frametitle{\(.*\)}.*/{s//\1/;h;n;s/\([^\]*\).*/\1/;H;:a;n;/^\\rowcolor{\(.*\)}.*/{s//\1/;H};/^}/!ba;g;s/\n/,/gp}' file
```

This is a filtering job, so use the `-n` option to only print what you want.

The data required exists between a line starting `\frame{\frametitle{...}` and ends with a line staring `}`.

Using the above criteria, copy the required matching data into the hold space and on encountering the end of the match, replace the current line by this copied data.

The data will be delimited by newlines, so replace these by commas and print out the result.

Comment: Thx that worked on linux, seemed like gnu sed for windows works differently. Or it has something to do with the windows line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Like this using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in *multiline mode*:

```
perl -0ne '
    my @a = ( 
        /.*?frametitle\{(\w+)\}\R                           # first line
        (\w+)                                               # second line
        .*rowcolor\{(\w+).*rowcolor\{(\w+).*rowcolor\{(\w+) # other lines
        /sx
    );
    END{
        print join(",", @a) . "\n";
    }
' file
```